# ituneslibrary framework iOS 8 beta

Tags: ios, xcode6, ituneslibrary

I am extremely new to world of iOS development.  I am impressed by the speed I am realizing my ideas. Making good use of MPMediaQuery and such like.

However I am struggling with plugging in the **iTuneslibrary framework**.  My intended usage will be minimal.

After code signing my app and updating the search path for framework search paths inside build settings (/Library/Frameworks). On compiling simple code sample; I am receiving the following error:

> Ld /Users/andyfives/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testiTunes-eyyuvregjcsyukesjqbswsnpckog/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testiTunes.app/testiTunes normal armv7
>       cd /Users/andyfives/Development/Objective-C/testiTunes
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/andyfives/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testiTunes-eyyuvregjcsyukesjqbswsnpckog/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/andyfives/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testiTunes-eyyuvregjcsyukesjqbswsnpckog/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/andyfives/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testiTunes-eyyuvregjcsyukesjqbswsnpckog/Build/Intermediates/testiTunes.build/Debug-iphoneos/testiTunes.build/Objects-normal/armv7/testiTunes.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -framework iTunesLibrary -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/andyfives/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testiTunes-eyyuvregjcsyukesjqbswsnpckog/Build/Intermediates/testiTunes.build/Debug-iphoneos/testiTunes.build/Objects-normal/armv7/testiTunes_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/andyfives/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testiTunes-eyyuvregjcsyukesjqbswsnpckog/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/testiTunes.app/testiTunes
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/iTunesLibrary, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/iTunesLibrary (2 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ITLibrary", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

I have searched all around; with no luck.  Can anyone help me or should I focus on another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The iTunesLibrary.framework is for OS X and not iOS.**

it isn't compiled for arm AND needs itunes 11 too

---

you might want the 'Media Player framework'

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.  I am now going to try the iTunes search API instead!